# MongooseError: Query was already executed: Users.find({ username: 'b' })

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

Code block:

```
export const getFollowers = async (req,res) => {
                console.log(req.body)
                const profilename=req.body.profilename
                const followingarray = []
              
                try{
             await userModel.find({username:profilename},async (err,data)=> {
                const following = data[0].following
         
              
                following.map(async(whoimFollowing)=>{
                  
                await userModel.find({username:whoimFollowing},async (err,whoimFollowingdata)=> {
                       console.log(whoimFollowingdata) 
                       followingarray.push(whoimFollowingdata)
                    
                    })
        
                })
           
             }).then((res)=> {
           
             })
                }catch(e){
                   
                }
            }
```

When I added await to the `UserModel.find` Thats when this error was caused,
How Can I Stop This Error From Happening?

Comment: Your question is not clear. As in your code Your have created a constant with message `'Query was already executed:` So Why have you added it in your question? add more clearification

Comment: You code requires proper usage of async-await. For example, `await userModel.find({...` returns the result from the find method execution, so the code can be: `const users_found = await userModel.find({...` - the the usage of callback is not required. See [Promises and Callbacks](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/promises/) with MongoDB NodeJS driver.

Answer (score 2):

the function itself is a callback so adding the async to the `getFollowers()` is what is causing the error. Remove the `async` with the `try` and `catch` from the `getFollowers()` and the code will work.

```
export const getFollowers = () => {
    console.log(req.body)
    ...
    ...
    userModel.find({...,async (err,data) => {...}})
}
```